# Adding extra power to USB power lines

Tags: power-supply, usb, raspberry-pi, usb-c

I see many posts regarding adding more power to supplement USB ports power but could not find a good answer how it can be done. My configuration is like this (except the red line):

[image]

I have a raspberry Pi computer powered by a 5v 10 amps power supply. A phone is connected to the compute using using a standard USB cable. The phone is in tethered mode and raspberry pi is connecting to Internet over that link. Now, since the configuration is supposed to run for long time the small amount of power raspberry pi is supplying through the USB line is not enough. So, I plan to add the red line in the diagram. Basically connecting the positive terminal to the usb ports positive / power line (I was thinking about using a diode - but then it'll drop .7v which is not acceptable) after measuring the voltages of each side using the USB ground as common and making sure those are same.

My logic is both of the systems are powered from same power supply - so if the voltages are same on the battery terminal and USB ports positive terminal it should be safe. I am not sure how the internals of the USB port works on a raspberry pi. So, wanted to discuss what else should I test or if the idea is valid at all.

Update:

One possibility I see is to use USB Power delivery protocol as described here: [https://www.ti.com/interface/usb/type-c-and-power-delivery/getting-started.html#:~:text=USB%20Power%20Delivery%20(PD)%20is,power%20level%20for%20each%20application](https://www.ti.com/interface/usb/type-c-and-power-delivery/getting-started.html#:%7E:text=USB%20Power%20Delivery%20(PD)%20is,power%20level%20for%20each%20application). It states that the system must negotiate first to use the system. And I know the phone I am using supports PS Fast charging. So, while it may not be possible to use simple wires to accomplish the task, using a TI chip from the link may solve the problem.

Also for 5V and up to 3amps there is the CC controller - that is about 15 watts (6 times more than normal 500 ma USB power).

I'll do more research and if I find a solution, add that here as it seems to be a common problem without a solid guideline of what works and what does not that cab be easily found for EEE novices like me.

Update 2: I eventually used a PD chip for negotiating the power from host device/charger. Just search for "usb c PD controller" and a lot of them will show up. You can use a voltage divider to control current and voltage using the CC line of usb c connector from charger using the chip. The phone side already have this capability and it'll be negotiating with the chip. Just have enough power at the source and it'll be OK. There are ready made reference design as well on digikey. Very simple and elegant solution.

Comment: This represents a misunderstanding of the nature of the actual problem.  Sure, you could route more power to the USB jack by using heavier wires for lower loss, but that wan't do any good.  The actual problem is that  a properly designed phone won't pull more than the USB power limit when connected to an active USB port.  It will only do that when connected to a port acting as a charger, not a USB host, and in traditional USB, that's incompatible with data interchange.

Comment: Site rules: *Questions on the use of electronic devices are off-topic as this site is intended specifically for questions on electronics design.* - this may seem harsh but unless you have good techy details of all components (and I note that all three are commercial devices), then it's guesswork. However, if you do have all the techy details then maybe there's something you don't understand about those details?

Comment: @ChrisStratton Thanks for the explanation. The key point I get is when the phone (any USB device) is communicating with other device through data channel it can not pull more power for charging. So, only way to charge with more power is to stop communicating and charge with a charge cable that provide high power. Now given that I wonder how comma.ai guys actually are able to bypass this limitations. May be a question on their forum- but there must be a trick to bypass that - as they are definitely doing it on phone (of course most probably without opening phone cover).

Comment: @Andyaka I understand what you are saying- but this is a problem about how to design a power supply unit. The inclusion of device explains how I am planning to use the power supply. My question is mostly about how do I supplement power of an USP port without altering anything of a USB compliant device. If it was not clear from the question, may be I should edit the question somehow to make it clear.

Comment: I am looking for a way to replicate what this ( https://www.amazon.com/Version-Splitter-Charger-Adapter-Samsung/dp/B07MP4X9RD/)  connector does but for data instead of audio only. May be I should just buy one and try for data.

Comment: I think the standard solution here is to get a data hub that supports USB-PD. That way your phone can negotiate a higher power limit instead of the usual 500mA.

Answer (score 2):

As Chris Stratton commented above, "a properly designed phone won't pull more than the USB power limit when connected to an active USB port." The point here is that it is the phone/device that determines how much power it can sink, and for what purpose. Simple beefing up of power wires or having more capable power supply cannnot possible solve this problem.

To maintain (or charge) the phone's battery while operating in data transfer mode, the phone must be designed to do so, and it can do it only if the host port also has corresponding capabilities.

With newer USB connection standard as Type-C connector with Power Deliver function, the solution to the question is possible, but again, both link partners must have corresponding matching capabilities designed in.

The USB-C with PD works in the following way. After the cable makes an interconnect, DC voltages on CC lines are used to determine primary ports functionality. In the case of smartphone, it will likely advertise itself as "device/sink", while the host port might have dual-role in terms of power - it can be a standard host source, or as a power sink (to be able to charge itself if this is a laptop).

After the direction of connection (for power) is determined after few CC-Rp-Rd cycles, the link partners exchange "capability" messages over the PD serial communication over the same CC lines. This communication provides both host and device with what they want and what they can do in terms of power, and "power contract" gets negotiated. Then there is a round of negotiations that takes place about the DATA role of the ports, and about supprt of any other alternative modes (display port, audio, debug, etc). Only after that the link partners begin USB-level communication, in negotiated direction.

All this functionality must have internal support and is controlled over several internal communnication links between CPU, Embedded Controller (EC), and PD/CC chips (and other possible data muxes). All this control is embedded in various BIOS functions and firmware patches for EC. So this is not something a DYI person can do, these functions must be designed and qualified/validated by device/host manufacturers.

Comment: Interesting in a technical sense, though likely getting a bit off topic, is this something where the source role could be played by a powered hub (as proposed in a comment), or does the scheme necessarily have to involve the actual host stack?

Comment: @ChrisStratton, this is a good question. Managing power requests and data roles require significant intelligence. Even managing the basic Type-C connectivity in Windows is implemented as a BIOS-involved service with interface to a special USB-C manager and corresponding "UCM-UCSI ACPI" driver. A hub, in theory, must collect all power requirements from connected devices, and advertise the compounded value upstream, dynamically. Up to date (end of 2020) I have not seen any hubs or docks that can do this, frequently causing problems. I don't know what MS theory is about this.

Comment: It sounds like you're saying the asker may be out of luck.  Historically speaking many phones/tablets haven't offered wonderful data channels over USB between a host PC and 3rd party apps anyway, so it's not uncommon to see a captive tablet on something that's simply wired to power it as a charger, while actually using wifi for communication with the rest of the system.  Inelegant, but the integrators went with what they could actually make work.

Comment: @ChrisStratton, the asker is definitely and unconditionally out of luck :-(